# create predefined hash table with multiple columns in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to set multiple values for my hash table and to add manually data.
Like this:

```
$hash = $null

$hash = @{AppName = "1"; AppLocator = "11"; Id = "22"; ServerDB = "121"; ServerApp = "12"; Database = "121"}
$hash += @{AppName = "test"; AppLocator = "1dsdf1"; Id = "22fdsd"; ServerDB = "1sdfds21"; ServerApp = "12"; Database = "121"}
$hashes += $hash

$hashes
```

but I am getting only the first set of data.
I also tried via $hash.Add but no luck.

Thanks

Comment: That's not how hash tables work. What are you trying to accomplish exactly? :)

Comment: Maybe an arraylist of hash tables? 

Comment: I need to setup different parameters of each item. I have 14 items. Some items uses same parameters (Id, ServerDBName, ServerApp...) and someone not. I was thinking some kine of creation of a new PS-Object with properties like : `$hash = New-Object PSObject -property @{State="Alaska";Temp="Cold";Travel="Car"}`

Comment: Probably a better idea to go with the objects. Create an array first and add each object to the array.

Comment: @arco444 Yeah, I will go in that way. Thanks!